# How to run file in windows CMD with node

Tags: linux, node.js, windows, bash, npm

I am running this line in `Linux` without problems

```
> npm run setup-hooks -s
> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried to get this file to run in windows but just can't get my head round it, trying with `npm run` inside of the `package.json` but just can't work out how.

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "setup-hooks": "./scripts/setup-hooks",
    "preinstall": "npm run install-eslint -s && npm run prepare-hooks -s && npm run setup-hooks -s"
  },
```

**setup-hooks**

```
#!/bin/sh

#DON'T SETUP THE HOOKS IF YOU ARE IN CI
if [ "$CONTINUOUS_INTEGRATION" != "true" ]; then
  echo "Setting pre-commit hook"
  ln -f -s "$PWD/scripts/pre-commit" .git/hooks/pre-commit

  echo "Setting pre-push hook"
  ln -f -s "$PWD/scripts/pre-push" .git/hooks/pre-push
fi
```

So I would like to be able to call this file `./scripts/setup-hooks` from both linux and windows.

Answer (score 1):

Your `setup-hooks` file is a shell file, which is not supported by default on windows.

You will need to install something like [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) which comes with a great bash emulator. Alternatively you can try [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or [Powershell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx)

Running `npm run setup-hooks` will call whatever command you have in the `setup-hooks` as if it were an executable. If you simply tried running `./scripts/setup-hooks` from within that folder using git bash, it will most likely fail. Try adding the `.sh` extension to encourage git bash to recognize it as an executable:

`./scripts/setup-hooks.sh`

Comment: Good point, I am actually using `git bash` already though :( `Hutber@hutber-pc /c/var/www/mol-videojs-ima (master)
$ npm run setup-hooks -s
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` So i thought it had more to do with the way node was trying to run `scripts.setup-hooks`

Comment: See addtional comments above.